# Is there a way make characters in a regex replace string conditional?

Tags: regex

I would like to match a five digit zip code or a nine digit zip code.  I would like to add a hyphen in the replacement string if there are nine digit, regardless if the there was one to begin with.

I'm using `^(\d{5})-?(\d{4})?$` for the search and `$1-$2` for the replacement.

If I start with `12345` I get back `12345-`. I don't want the trailing hyphen.

Is there a way to specify in the replacement string that the hyphen should only be shown if $2 not empty?

Is there a way to inject a hyphen into the search string even if there wasn't one there to begin with, so I could exclude it from the replacement string?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do this purelly with regex, but you can easely do it on java (it seems that you are using it)

Comment: you could put the hyphen into the second parenthesis.

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: @MaineMike: If you are using Notepad++ or any other Boost-based tool/platform, there is a solution: `(?2$1-$2:$1)`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, It seems that it is a false problem.

According to your pattern, a five digits number originaly can't contain an hyphen, a nine digits number may have an hyphen after the fifth digit.

So, to add an hyphen to all nine digits numbers, you only need to match nine digits numbers that haven't an hyphen, all other cases can be ignored, isn't it?

search:       `^([0-9]{5})([0-9]{4})$`

replacement:  `$1-$2`

Comment: I understand your point but I think that OP is running into some kind of a list that He needs to validate and in that list there are things besides the 5/9 digits. If that is not the case you are entirelly right.

Comment: @JorgeCampos: Perhaps, nobody knows, in any case, a substitution and a validation are two different tasks.

Comment: Yeah, totally agree. But for the specific question on the title the answer is a simple No, right?!

Comment: @JorgeCampos: You can't with a basic replacement, the only ways are: the use of a callback function as replacement, or to concatenate needed characters to the string before processing it *(if not already present in the string)*.

Comment: Thank you Jorge.  I suspected that there is no way to do it in one step, but I wasn't sure.  FYI.  I was thinking about building a table of regex expressions to validate form data and another table to format valid data.  If I consider zips in the form of 12345, 12345-1234, and 123451234 valid, then I was hoping there would be a single replacement operation that would add the hyphen only if the original string was 9 digits with no hyphen.